# wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed - after update from from ubuntu 16.04 LTS to ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: apt, 20.04

After Upgrading to `ubuntu 20.04`, I wanted to uninstall `playonlinux` and it shows errors:

`$ sudo apt-get purge playonlinux`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed
 wine1.6-i386:i386 : Depends: wine1.6:any (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2)
                     Recommends: libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: wine-gecko2.21:i386 but it is not installable
                     Recommends: wine-mono0.0.8:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

---

`$ sudo apt --fix-broken install`

This command shows error. Because wine 1.6 is not compatible with ubuntu 20.04

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-wine libfaudio0 libllvm11 libllvm11:i386 libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libstb0 libvkd3d1 libwine libxdamage1:i386 shim wine64
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libp11-kit-gnome-keyring wine1.6 wine1.6-amd64
Suggested packages:
  dosbox:any winbind
Recommended packages:
  fonts-droid wine-gecko2.21 wine-mono0.0.8
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libp11-kit-gnome-keyring wine1.6 wine1.6-amd64
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 17.0 MB/17.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 129 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 wine1.6-amd64 amd64 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2 [16.1 MB]                                                                                         
Get:2 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 wine1.6 amd64 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2 [864 kB]                                                                                                
Fetched 17.0 MB in 25s (689 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                 
(Reading database ... 311936 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../wine1.6-amd64_1%3a1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wine1.6-amd64 (1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/wine1.6-amd64_1%3a1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wine/windowscodecs.dll.so', which is also in package libwine:amd64 5.0-3ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../wine1.6_1%3a1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wine1.6 (1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/wine1.6_1%3a1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/wine/fonts/couree.fon', which is also in package fonts-wine 5.0-3ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../libp11-kit-gnome-keyring_3.18.3-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:amd64 (3.18.3-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libp11-kit-gnome-keyring_3.18.3-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/p11-kit/modules/gnome-keyring.module', which is also in package gnome-keyring-pkcs11:amd64 3.36.0-1ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/wine1.6-amd64_1%3a1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/wine1.6_1%3a1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libp11-kit-gnome-keyring_3.18.3-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

##### And `ubuntu software updater` was not working. So, it was a disaster.

I found the solution, and I have added the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

At last I have found the issue.

When I run `$ sudo apt-get update` I see `xenial-updates` in the list.

```
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                           
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                              
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                              
Hit:5 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal InRelease                                                          
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                       
Hit:8 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                            
Hit:9 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                  
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:7 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Fetched 328 kB in 4s (89.5 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

**But xenial is for ubuntu 16.04**. So, I have to remove this.

I was looking for in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. But not found.
Then I found it in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial.list` file and commented all lines [by adding #(hash) before each line], and saved file.

```
# deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main
# deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
#deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
```

Now I run `$ sudo apt --fix-broken install`. And it removed the old version of `playonlinux wine wine1.6-i386:i386 winetricks`.

And now everything works.

So, when upgrade OS version, you must have to remove software source of older OS version.

I hope it helps someone. Thanks.